# How to change status bar on iOS Simulator to Apple default like time: 9:41

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, statusbar

I want to take Screenshots with different devices. Is there like a terminal command to change the status bar manually. I know there is `xcrun` but how do I use it?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364912

Comment: Thanks @BrunoBieri but YanvegHD answer already helped

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the command you need to run on your terminal :

`xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "9:41" --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100 --cellularBars 4`

This will change the values for all booted simulators.

You can replace 'booted' by the device name (example "iPhone 11 Pro"), or by the UUID of the simulator.

( `xcrun simctl list | grep Booted` to find UUIDs of running simulators)

And voilà ! You can also change the values for the time and the battery if you want to :)

Comment: You need a simulator running iOS 13 or later and Xcode 11 as minimum.

Comment: For me the cellular bars are empty, adding `--cellularBars 4` to the command helped.

Comment: For me this no longer has any effect in Simulator 14.3

Comment: It works for me but now with Xcode 14.3.1 and rosetta destination sim, it does not work :(

Comment: I tried using the simulator name, UUID and tried updating to Xcode 14.3.1, and it still doesn't work...